# How to Add commas to Values being updated with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that calculates how many (puppies and kittens) are being per second. It uses Date() to calculate how many have been born sine the beginning of the week an the beginning of the month. But I'm having difficulty updating this script to add commas at the thousands, millions, billions mark. Can someone please show me the best way to add commas in this script?

here goes the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJy4x/35)

```
var start = new Date(),
    midnight = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate(), 0),
    first = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), 1);

var now = new Date(),
    secondsFromStart = Math.floor((now - start)/1000),
    secondsFromMidnight = Math.floor((now - midnight)/1000),
    secondsFromFirst = Math.floor((now - first)/1000);

var elems = [];
$(".s").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var BornPerSec = $this.data("quantity"),
        Start = secondsFromStart*BornPerSec,
        Midnight = secondsFromMidnight*BornPerSec,
        First = secondsFromFirst*BornPerSec;
    elems.push({
        obj: $this,
        BornPerSec: BornPerSec,
        Start : Start,
        Midnight : Midnight,
        First : First,       
        now: $this.children('.now'),
        morning: $this.children('.morning'),
        month: $this.children('.month'),
     });
});
setInterval(function () {
    $.each(elems,function(i,n){
        n.Start+=n.BornPerSec;
        n.Midnight+=n.BornPerSec;
        n.First+=n.BornPerSec;
        n.now.text(n.Start % 1 === 0 ?n.Start: n.Start.toFixed(2));
        n.morning.text(n.Midnight % 1 === 0 ?n.Midnight:n.Midnight.toFixed(2));
        n.month.text(n.First % 1 === 0 ?n.First:n.First.toFixed(2));
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks, but this question is not really a dupe as the values are always being updated

Comment: it's how you get the separators that counts, which is what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use this function:

```
function numberWithCommas( x ) {
    return x.toString().replace( /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gJy4x/37/)